# getting data from 2 tables - once with count, once without

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have table with groups

**id | groupName**

and then users (which does not matter here)

**id | userName**

and then mapping map-group-user

**id | groupId | userId**

On first step I wanted to know how many users are in every group ...

```
SELECT             
g.groupName as name,  count(DISTINCT m.groupId, m.userId) as totalCount             
FROM group g             
LEFT JOIN map-group-user m ON ( g.id = m.groupId)              
GROUP BY g.id
```

this works... my results are:

**name | totalCount**

**group1 | 34**

**group2 | 23**

**group3 | 11**

now i want to add another column in same results ... i want to know if specific user (lets say userId = 1) is added to this specific group (so not only count how many users joined the group, but also to know in which groups my user is)
so in same query I want to check if in map-group-user there is entry for each group for my userId (1)

so I'd like results like that:

**name | totalCount | myUser**

**group1 | 34 | 1**

**group2 | 23 | 0**

**group3 | 11 | 1**

so myUser = 1 where he is in group already...

i hope my explanations are clear :)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this as a column in your select:

```
CASE
    WHEN m.userId = 541 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END as myUser
```

In my example the ID of your user is 541. So like this:

```
SELECT g.groupName as name
       , count(DISTINCT m.groupId, m.userId) as totalCount             
       , sum(CASE
            WHEN m.userId = 541 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END) as myUser
FROM `group` as g             
LEFT JOIN `map-group-user` as m ON (g.id = m.groupId)              
GROUP BY g.groupName
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=40b7a26f1a526b56191262668dbd0b58)

Comment: The `DISTINCT` can be simplified to `DISTINCT m.userId`.

Comment: I am looking at the table name "group". Will it cause any problems ?

Comment: Probably yes. Maybe it should be enclosed in back ticks.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for quick answer. I think that's what I need although small fix might be needed somewhere... I get SQL syntax error... I'm preparing fiddle to visualize it...

Comment: @MichaelZet have you done it with the back ticks - I have updated it minute ago. Thanks to The Impaler.

Comment: @MichaelZet  I have created a DEMO for you to see. The data is not great but it is there :) I have added one change and I believe you will find it correct now. P.S. Your query from your question also has a bug: it should be  `GROUP BY g.groupName`  and not `GROUP BY g.id `

Comment: Yes - all great!! Thank you for super fast help! Highly appreciated. This is what I wanted.

Comment: @VBokšić more than happy to do that. I would upvote but my rating is too low :( thanks again!

Comment: Soon you will be able to do it. I believe 15 is needed but no problem. Thanks for this and you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your `distinct` would seem to be unnecessary.  Presumably, the `group-members` table doesn't have duplicates.  With that observation, I would recommend:

```
SELECT g.groupName as name, count(*) as totalCount,
       sum( gu.user_id = 541 ) as myUser             
FROM group g LEFT JOIN
     map_group_user gu
     ON g.id = gu.groupId             
GROUP BY g.id;
```

Comment: @MichaelZet . . . It is a simpler and faster solution, which is why I suggested it.